# Remove package version from Pypi

Tags: python, pip, pypi

How to remove a specific **version** of a package from `Pypi`? 
Now it's impossible to do that from the web interface and `twine` doesn't have such an option.

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to delete a package version from the PyPI web interface as follows:

- Log in to PyPI
- Go to https://pypi.org/manage/projects/ (reachable from the main page via the "Your projects" item in the "Welcome back, NAME" dropdown)
- Click on the "Manage" button next to the relevant project
- In the "Options" dropdown next to the version you want to delete, select "Delete"

Comment: I'm just a maintainer (not the owner) of that package and sadly I can't access "Manage" option

Comment: In that case, you either need to be given the "Owner" role, or ask an owner to delete the version.